# With RSpec, how can you check an elements contents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to check that an element's contents match a certain regex. The following doesn't work... what do you do to get this to work in Rails 3.1?

```
rendered.should have_selector('.test-heading', text: /test/i)
```

Answer (score 0):

have_selector is matcher from Capybara. You should add Capybara gem to Gemfile.

Comment: Capybara is being used. The problem is something to do with the text:regex.

Answer (score 0):

your gemfile should have sth like:

```
group :test do
  .
  .
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1' #whatever their versions are..
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  .
  .
end
```

execute bundle install,

then do something

```
it { should have_selector('id_name_here', text: 'content_here') }
```

Comment: I know that text:'exact match' works but I want to do a regex... there's got to be a way to do that.